# IONIC 3 android application start delay

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I had developed application for my Android, with the following Ionic configuration,

```
@Ionic\App script : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms : Android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework : Ionic Angular 3.9.2
Ionic CLI Version : 3.20.0
```

When I open my application, It shows white screen up to 3 to 5 Seconds, After that only I can able to view my application screen. How to reduce this app open delay ?
When I build my application I had used the following command also

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Even It opens with the same delay ?

**Note**: 
I don’t want to show splash screen on my application. Native apps opens immediately, but ionic apps taking too much time to open

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, researching a lot of it, the solution I found was to just add more time to the splash screen. This delay is due to the connection between the native modules and web modules.

Those are the disadvantage working with hybrid apps. Also you can check if the Ionic 4 upgrade solved this issue and upgrade yours.

Answer (score 0):

`run --list --prod` does not generate the "final" version in apk.
To get the delay you need to generate the "final" version with `zipalign`.
Remember that before it is necessary to generate the key with the `jarsigner -verbose`